# How to create a faceted search in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, faceted-search

I have the following tables with which i'm trying to create a faceted search

```
facets

facet_id | facet_name
--------------------
 1       | LANGUAGES
 2       | INDUSTRIES
 3       | JOB TYPES
 4       | SALARIES
 5       | LOCATIONS

job_facts (Note: this is a view)

job_id | facet_id | value
----------------------------------------
 1     | 1        | French
 1     | 2        | Sales
 1     | 3        | Permanent
 1     | 4        | 15000-20000
 1     | 5        | New York
 2     | 1        | French
 2     | 1        | Dutch
 2     | 2        | Sales
 2     | 2        | Media
 2     | 3        | Temporary
 2     | 4        | 20000-25000
 2     | 4        | 25000-30000
 2     | 5        | New York
 3     | 1        | German
 3     | 2        | Accounts
 3     | 3        | Permanent
 3     | 4        | 10000-15000
 3     | 5        | Paris
 4     | 1        | Spanish
 4     | 2        | Marketing
 4     | 3        | Permanent
 4     | 4        | 15000-20000
 4     | 5        | London
```

I can produce the intial results and the faceted navigation using the SQL below:

```
# SQL To retrieve job data: 

SELECT * FROM jobs

# SQL To construct the intial HTML faceted navigation:

SELECT t2.facet_name
        , t1.value
        , count(*) AS c
FROM job_facts t1
INNER JOIN facets t2 ON t1.facet_id = t2.facet_id
GROUP BY t2.facet_name, t1.value
```

The html faced nav would appear as follows:

```
> LANGUAGES
    French (2)
    German (1)
    Spanish (1)
    Dutch (1)

> INDUSTRIES
    Sales (2)
    Accounts (1)
    Media (1)
    Marketing (1)

> JOB TYPES
    permanent (3)
    temporary (1)

> SALARIES
    10000-15000 (1)
    15000-20000 (2)
    20000-25000 (1)
    25000-30000 (1)

> LOCATIONS
    New York (2)
    Paris (1)
    London (1)
```

I'm stuck on how to contruct the SQL to produce the facet navigation and the job results dynamically as the user starts selecting multiple facets. Eg if the user clicked on the facet 'French', the nav should display as follows:

```
> LANGUAGES
    French X

> INDUSTRIES
    Sales (2)
    Media (1)

> JOB TYPES
    permanent (1)
    temporary (1) 

> SALARIES
    15000-20000 (1)
    20000-25000 (1)
    25000-30000 (1)

> LOCATIONS
    New York (2)


#The results would list:

job_id | title                           | jobtype_id | location_id | post_dt    | exp_dt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     | French Sales Job                | 1          | 1           |   2015-04-01 | 2015-05-01
 2     | French & Dutch Sales Media Job  | 2          | 1           | 2015-04-01 | 2015-05-01
```

If the user drills down further and select the facet 'temporary' the nav and results should display as follows:

```
> LANGUAGES
   French X

> INDUSTRIES
   Sales (1)
   Media (1)

> JOB TYPES
   temporary X

> SALARIES
   20000-25000 (1)
   25000-30000 (1)

> LOCATIONS
   New York (1)

#the results would list:

job_id | title                           | jobtype_id | location_id | post_dt    | exp_dt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2     | French & Dutch Sales Media Job  | 2          | 1           | 2015-04-01 | 2015-05-01
```

What would be the SQL to modify the jobs results and the facet navigation? Does any one know of a more elegant way to achieve this? Unfortunately I cant use Solr due to being on a hosted platform.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

EAV schema is a bear to code for.  And it does not scale well.  And yours is even worse because each facet can be multi-valued.

You need to do a "self-join".  The main part of the SELECT is similar to your query.  Then `JOIN USING(job_id)` back to the same pair of tables, but this time have `AND facet_id = 1 AND value = 'French'`.  Something like

```
SELECT  t2.facet_name , t1.value , count(*) AS c
    FROM  job_facts t1
    JOIN  facets t2 ON t1.facet_id = t2.facet_id
    JOIN  job_facts t3 ON t1.job_id = t3.job_id
    WHERE  facet_id = 1  AND  value = 'French' -- what they selected
    GROUP BY  t2.facet_name, t1.value
```